# How do I solve "Unable to render story <component> as the component annotation is missing from the default export" in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm new to Storybook and am setting up my first React components and Stories file, as such:

**Button.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Button({title}) {
  return (
    <div className="button">
       {title}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Button.stories.js**

```
import { Button } from './Button';

export default {
  component: Button,
};

export const Primary = {
  title: "Primary"
};
```

However, I am getting error

```
Unable to render story components-button--primary as the component annotation is missing from the default export
```

in Storybook.

I'm really not sure what this means and Google is not giving me anything.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to import the `"Button"` component in your "Button.stories.js" file, which is creating the problem. Because the component is exported as the default export, it should be imported without the need of curly brackets.

```
import Button from './Button';
```

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the curly braces but still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

try exporting component like this

`import React from "react";`

`function Button({title}) { }`

`export default Button`

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because you are exporting a `default` component from `Button.jsx` but importing a `named component` from that same file in `Button.stories.js`. Long story short, you are mixing your import and export strategies.

To fix this, all you have to do is change your import.

```js
import Button from './Button';

export default {
  component: Button,
};

export const Primary = {
  title: "Primary"
};
```

Alternatively, you could opt to change the export instead.

```js
export function Button({ title }) {
  return (
    <div className="button">
       {title}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You only need to do one of these.

And remember it is important to always `import` your components the same way you `export` theme. E.g.

You can export/import named components like so:

```
// Export named component
export const Component = () => <div>Some Component</div>

// import named component
import { Component } from 'path/to/component'
```

You can export/import default components like so:

```
// export default
const Component = () => <div>Some Component</div>

export default Component

// import Default Component
import ComponentOne from 'path/to/component'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but no change. Get the same results